# ¿Cómo vaciar formulario después de enviarlo?

Tags: php, html

Al enviar el formulario lo hace correctamente, pero al darle a la tecla f5 me sale la alerta de **Si deseo reenviar el formulario**. Entonces me preguntaba cómo vaciar el formulario después de enviarlo en php, utilizar el método header funciona pero quiero vaciarlo para no hacer header en cada formulario que haga y así no solucionar el problema a medias o superficialmente.

```
if(isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"])){
    $texto = $_POST["_fullMessage"];
    if(!empty($_POST["_fullMessage"])){
        $seleccion = $db->query("SELECT * FROM site_news_comments WHERE user_id = '". USER_ID . "' AND news_id = '". $_id ."'");
        if($seleccion->num_rows == 1){
            $tpl->assign('success', $light->error('Solo podrás comentar una (1) sola vez.'));
        }
        else{
        $db->query("INSERT INTO site_news_comments (news_id,user_id,timestamp,body) VALUES ('".$_id."','". USER_ID . "', '". time() . "', '". $texto . "')");
        unset($texto);
    }
    }
    else{
        $tpl->assign('success', $light->error('No dejes campos vacios.'));
    }
}

 <form method='post' align='center'>
        <center>
        {$success}
        <textarea name="_fullMessage" style="width:500px;height: 50px;" maxlength="200"></textarea>
        </center>
        <br />
            <input class='btblack' type='submit' name='_commentSubmit' value='Comentar'>
    </form>
```

Comment: puedes recargar la pagina y se resetean los datos

Comment: Lo haría, pero no deseo solucionarlo de esa forma. Me recomendaron utilizar unset() pero no sé si lo utilicé bien.

Comment: `unset`es del lado del servidor por lo que no te va a funcionar. Habría que ver tu formulario y como haces el envío para poder responderte exactamente.

Comment: con php se podria declarando las variables a vacias despues de haber echo el POST

Comment: @JDev, ya añadí el formulario. Echenle un vistazo.

Comment: Hum el problema no es vacíar el formulario pues puedes vaciarlo y te seguiria dando el mismo problema. Al hacer un f5 lo que hace el navegador es repetir la ultima petición y está es la que envío los datos y por eso te hace esa pregunta. Lo mejor sería hacer la petición via ajax y luego con JS/JQuery limpiar el formulario si lo necesitas.

Comment: Agrega `_commentSubmit.reset();` al enviar el formulario